# extract substring between "-" and "-" in string in R

Tags: r, string, substring

i have a  list of string that looks like this:

`list=["chr21-10139833-A-C","chry-10139832-b-f"]`

for every string in the list i need to extract the numbers between "-" and "-"

so i would get:

`[10139833,10139832]`

i tried this :

`gsub(".*[-]([^-]+)[-]", "\\1", list`

but it returns :

`[ac,bf]`

what can i do to make it work ? thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `str_extract` from `stringr` we can try:

```r
list <- c("chr21-10139833-A-C", "chry-10139832-b-f")
nums <- str_extract(list, "(?<=-)(\\d+)(?=-)")
nums

[1] "10139833" "10139832"
```

We could also use `sub` for a base R option:

```r
list <- c("chr21-10139833-A-C", "chry-10139832-b-f")
nums <- sub(".*-(\\d+).*", "\\1", list)
nums

[1] "10139833" "10139832"
```

Answer (score 3):

**1)** Using the input shown in the Note at the end, use `read.table`.  If you want character output instead add `colClasses = "character"` argument to `read.table` .

```
read.table(text = x, sep = "-")[[2]]
## [1] 10139833 10139832
```

**2)** Another possibility is to use `strapply`.  If you want character output then omit the `as.numeric` argument.

```
library(gsubfn)
strapply(x, "-(\\d+)-", as.numeric, simplify = TRUE)
## [1] 10139833 10139832
```

### Note

```
x <- c("chr21-10139833-A-C", "chry-10139832-b-f")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_split_i` to get the `i`th split string:

```r
library(stringr)
str <- c("chr21-10139833-A-C", "chry-10139832-b-f")

str_split_i(str, "-", i = 2)
#[1] "10139833" "10139832"
```

Answer (score 1):

If your structure and character of your string are always like that with word characters and hyphens, you could match 1+ digits between word boundaries:

```
library(stringr)
list <- c("chr21-10139833-A-C", "chry-10139832-b-f")
str_extract(list, "\\b\\d+\\b")
```

Or with a perl like pattern and `\K` you might also use

```
list <- c("chr21-10139833-A-C", "chry-10139832-b-f")
regmatches(list, regexpr("-\\K\\d+(?=-)", list, perl = TRUE))
```

Both will output:

```
[1] "10139833" "10139832"
```